# I have issue of finding the negative results in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data calls SalesData that's contains "Profit", "Sales" and "Sub-Category"
and when I use this code

```
SubCategoryProfit = SalesData[["Sub-Category", "Profit"]].groupby(by = "Sub-Category").sum().sort_values(by = "Profit")
  #Print the results
  SalesData.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=['Profit','Sales'])
  print(SubCategoryProfit)
```

I will get these results

```
                 Profit
Sub-Category            
Tables       -17725.4811
Bookcases     -3472.5560
Supplies      -1189.0995
Fasteners       949.5182
Machines       3384.7569
Labels         5546.2540
Art            6527.7870
Envelopes      6964.1767
```

however when I am looking for the negative results only with this code

```
JustSubCatProf = SalesData[["Sub-Category", "Profit"]]
NegProfFilter = SalesData["Profit"] < 0.0 
JustNegSubCatProf = JustSubCatProf[NegProfFilter].groupby(by = "Sub-Category").sum().sort_values(by = "Profit")
print(JustNegSubCatProf)
```

I will get this!

```
                 Profit
Sub-Category            
Binders      -38510.4964
Tables       -32412.1483
Machines     -30118.6682
Bookcases    -12152.2060
Chairs        -9880.8413
Appliances    -8629.6412
Phones        -7530.6235
Furnishings   -6490.9134
Storage       -6426.3038
Supplies      -3015.6219
```

There should be only 3 negative results I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: With your first code snippet, you can use `SubCategoryProfit2 = SubCategoryProfit[SubCategoryProfit['Profit'] < 0]` to get only "negative profit rows" (which should be 3 rows).

Comment: Perfect That Worked! Thank you so much @cs95

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dataframe with negative values ​​by filtering as follows.

```
SalesData[SalesData["valuecol1"] < 0]
```

I cannot fully understand your problem as I cannot see exactly what data it has. If you can share some of the data, I can give a clearer answer.

Comment: Hi here is the Data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ttF1WaF34t-xg2lEHOfYpZi2OAXSO6tK/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Once you have this result:

```
In [2878]: df
Out[2878]: 
                  Profit
Sub-Category            
Tables       -17725.4811
Bookcases     -3472.5560
Supplies      -1189.0995
Fasteners       949.5182
Machines       3384.7569
Labels         5546.2540
Art            6527.7870
Envelopes      6964.1767
```

You can do this to get only `-ve` rows:

```
In [2880]: df[df.Profit.lt(0)]
Out[2880]: 
                  Profit
Sub-Category            
Tables       -17725.4811
Bookcases     -3472.5560
Supplies      -1189.0995
```